# No banner in Configurable banner form

Tags: install4j

I've added a "configurable banner form." If I clear to reset the "image for banner", the banner shows the default banner. I want no banner. How can I implement this?

I also want to change the font of the "Screen title" in the "Configurable banner form." Is this possible? How would I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a "Configurable form" for a form instead, which does not have a banner. Currently it's not possible to change the font size of the title, this is planned for install4j 6.

Comment: thank you for your response. but if I use "Configurable form", there is title bar. I don't want use title bar or banner...

Comment: That is currently not possible.